# What are all the types of UITableViewCellStyle?

Tags: swift, uitableview

What are all of the types of styles available to use in a table view? There's `.subtitle`, but what are the others?

Comment: Please take a moment to look at the documentation before posting such a question.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcellstyle) use Fail...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually only one type of table view cell built in — namely, UITableViewCell. You can use any of the four built-in basic styles:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcellstyle

...but you don't have to, and in most cases you'll probably prefer not to, as none of them are likely to suit your needs perfectly. So you probably will just make your own custom cell layout, giving it the subviews you actually need. When you do, you'll probably also want to subclass UITableViewCell so that you can make outlets to your content view's subviews.